# Invoking Azure function using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, console-application, azure-functions

I have written a simple Azure function that gets a name and returns a greeting message (as I am trying to get familiar with Azure functions...)
I want to trigger the functions in a simple Console Application that I wrote in C# using Visual Studio.
However, I can't get this to work. Everytime I run my code the console opens and immediately closes. I added Console.ReadLine() to try and avoid that but the same thing keeps on happening. **Note that the function is working correctly when using the URL in the browser.** The code I have written so far is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string nameToSend = "Testo";
    string baseURL = "*URLGOESHERE";
    string urlToInvoke = string.Format("{0}&name={1}", baseURL, nameToSend);
    Run(urlToInvoke);
}

public static async void Run(string i_URL)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(i_URL);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Help please!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through?  How about adding some error handling?

Comment: `Run` returns void, so main doesn't wait for it to finish and the program ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your call of `Run` with `Run(urlToInvoke).Wait();`. You have to wait for task completion.

Comment: It's not exactly what I needed to do, but the general concept of returning Task so the program waits is what solved the problem. Thanks.